# Drupal 7: Display by emdedding views

Tags: drupal-7

I have a content type "categories" and also a view named "categories". In content I have a title, an image, and then some description. I want to display them on my page -- front.tpl.php -- by emdedding views.

There are 5 such content having a title, an image and description.

Here is the code I have written, but it's not working:

```
<?php
$view = views_get_view('categories');
$view->set_display('page_1');
$view->pre_execute();
$view->execute();
if (!empty($view->result)) {
foreach ($view->result as $row => $values) {
$text = '';
$text =  $view->render_field('title', $row) ;
$field_categories_image .= '&lt;div&gt;' . $view-    >render_field('field_categories_image', $row) . '&lt;/div&gt;';
$image_url = file_create_url($field_categories_image[0]  ['http://localhost/drupal-7.34/sites/default/files/firefighter.jpg']);
$text = '<img src="'.$image_url.'"/>';
}
print $text;
}
$view->destroy();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hacking the template, I would do this through configuration by setting up a block display on the view in question in admin/structure/views/view/*categories*.  Then go to admin/structure/block to display the block where you want it on the frontpage.

Comment: Thank you ken klatt. It sounds easy but is there any best practice to take a view a page or block type? I took it as a page

Comment: You are not limited to one display type for a view.  You can create a view and then have multiple display types for it and then use them for different purposes on your site.  Perhaps you create a view of blog post teasers.  You could have a page display point to in a menu link and then a block display of the view that is configured to display in the sidebar of the frontpage.  Once creating a block display for a view and adding it to a container, I use the block_class module to give the block a css class to make applying styles to it easier.